# Relating lines of RTL dump to source code or assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly

Running gcc with "-fdump-rtl-expand" dumps the rtl representation of program. I was wondering if there is any way to relate the lines of this RTL dump to high level source code? Something like what "-Wa,-adhln -g" generates for intermix of source code and assembly.